# nest a form input under a checkbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, user-input

I have a number of form inputs that I want to submit based on whether it's checkbox is selected.

So for example, I want to have

```
checkbox - label - dropdown selection input
checkbox - label - text field input
checkbox - label - default value
```

where the dropdown selection and other input fields are only submitted to the form if their checkbox is selected.  If it's not checked then it would simply treat the field as blank.

Hope this was fairly clear,
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for rails to do it (its server side code so once the page is served its done). So you need to use Javascript.

Here is an example of what you are looking to do on my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matthewr/LzCDb/)

Comment: Very cool, thanks for this.  I think I may have worded the question wrong.  I'm not so much worried about enabling/disabling the entry, as much as I'm worried about what happens when the form is submitted.  I'd just like for the ones that are not checked to not be submitted.  Again, thanks for giving me this option.